# Google Charts - "this.ug is not a function"

Tags: javascript, json, google-visualization

I am attempting to populate a Google Chart from PHP code using [this example in their documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example).

By following the formatting precisely, I kept getting a JS error:  `this.ug is not a function`.

After hours of carefully inspecting the JSON endlessly in a formatter only to find the format perfect each time, I ended up creating a JSFiddle that replicates the issue using their own example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/pX36k/

What I've done here is, instead of using AJAX, I've simply copied the contents of their `sampleData.json` file as the `DataTable()` argument.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.DataTable({
                "cols": [
                    {"id":"","label":"Topping","pattern":"","type":"string"},
                    {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
                ],
                "rows": [
                    {"c":[{"v":"Mushrooms","f":null},{"v":3,"f":null}]},
                    {"c":[{"v":"Onions","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
                    {"c":[{"v":"Olives","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
                    {"c":[{"v":"Zucchini","f":null},{"v":1,"f":null}]},
                    {"c":[{"v":"Pepperoni","f":null},{"v":2,"f":null}]}
                ]
            });

            var options = {
                'width' : 400,
                'height' : 900
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the `new` before `google.visualization.DataTable(...)`.

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pX36k/1/).

Comment: I could kiss you.  Thanks so much!  That's what I get for coding 12 hours.  :/